# Why does a windows service create multiple instances of a service host

Tags: wcf

I am hosting a simple WCF service inside a windows service.  The WCF service itself creates TextWriterTraceListener to which it logs instrumentation data.

The strange thing is that even though the windows service hasn't restarted, it seems to keep creating new log files, and is writing the same log entries to multiple files.

The above behaviour can only happen if the constructor of MyService is being fired multiple times, basically every time a client connects to the service.  My undestanding and hope is that it will only create one instance of MyServiceBase and therefore only one instance of MyService (each time the windows service starts).

Of course I can work around this and check for how many listeners have been added to Trace, but I want to understand what is happening.

The code is as follows :

```
var ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
            { 
                new MyServiceBase() 
            };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);

public partial class MyServiceBase : ServiceBase
{
    ServiceHost _serviceHost;

    public MyServiceBase()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        _serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService));            
        _serviceHost.Open();

    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        if (_serviceHost != null)
        {
            _serviceHost.Close();
        }
        _serviceHost = null;
    }        
}

 public MyService()
    {         
        _fileListner = new TextWriterTraceListener(string.Format(@"{0}\Trace{1}.log", logDir, DateTime.Now.Ticks));
        Trace.Listeners.Add(_fileListner);
        WriteTraceMessage(string.Format("Service started {0}", DateTime.Now), new Guid("71961817-CB62-410f-AB44-43BFCE246847"));
    }
```

Comment: I'd also point out that the question title is inaccurate. There is a *single* Service Host that is creating multiple instances of the *service* class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How and when instances of `MyService` is created are controlled by WCF features such as the [`InstanceContextMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.instancecontextmode.aspx) (which is part of the `ServiceBehaviourAttribute`):

> Use the `InstanceContextMode` property to specify when new service objects are created. Because the service object is not directly connected to the communicating channel, the lifetime of the service objects is independent of the lifetime of the channel between a client and the service application. The default value, `PerSession`, instructs the service application to create a new service object when a new communication session is established between a client and the service application. Subsequent calls in the same session are handled by the same object.

There's also a good bit to read in [Sessions, Instancing and Concurrency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731193.aspx).

---

> My undestanding and hope is that it will only create one instance of `MyServiceBase` and therefore only one instance of `MyService`

But note that in your `OnStart` method, you're not creating a new `MyService` object - you're passing the *type* to the `ServiceHost`, because the host then uses the WCF attributes (or config) to determine lifetimes.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  And setting InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You start your servicehost with a type.

```
_serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService));
```

That means the servicehost has to create an instance. It will do so using the parameters mentioned in the other answers. If you don't want the servicehost to create the instance for you, you can give it an instance to use yourself:

```
_serviceHost = new ServiceHost(new MyService());
```

The servicehost will use this instance to handle all calls. You may want to put it into a variable first though.

Answer (score 0):

By Default instance context mode will be set to per session. So when ever a request comes it will create a new service instance. If you want to create only one instance per call then set the instance context mode=per call. if you want to create only one instance for whole application then set instance context mode=single.

For Your Reference check this link:
http://wcftutorial.net/Per-Call-Service.aspx

Comment: That is incorrect.  The default for `InstanceContextMode` is `PerSession`, not `PerCall`.  [ServiceBehaviorAttribute.InstanceContextMode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.instancecontextmode.aspx)